# Keycloak + Spring. Ignore certain APIs regardless of Authorization Header

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I want to allow certain APIs of pattern `api/v1/public/**` for all authenticated as well as anonymous users.

I have Keycloak adapter setup in my project, and my WebConfiguration looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class KeycloakWebConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

// ........ other methods .........//

  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/public/**");
    }
}
```

With this setup, when I call `/api/v1/public/ping` API without any headers, it works fine. I get the expected response.

However, if I add a random or empty Authorization header while making the request to the same api, it does not respond at all.

- Using Postman to make request, it says "There was an error connecting to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/public/ping".
- Using cURL terminal command to make request, it does not print anything and terminates the process.

If I make the same call again (using either postman or curl) without any header fields, it works perfectly fine again. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Did you able to find the answer to your issue?

Comment: I added a custom filter that removes the authentication header if the request path does not require authentication. It's not the best solution but I was able to do a workaround for it.

Comment: Ahh! In my case, I have two authentication method which authenticates with authentication header. So probably I have to separate authenticate style for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue using Springboot, but I was using Undertow instead of Tomcat. After a lot of strugle I decided to switch to Tomcat and it started working as expected - so seems this is a problem related to Keycloak integration with Undertow/Wildfly/JBoss and not Spring Security.